# PDF Couldn't Load From Network?

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, pdf-viewer, pdfview

```
      body: SfPdfViewer.network(
    'https://sajhaguides.files.wordpress.com/2022/02/class10optmath-1.pdf',
    key: _pdfViewerKey,
  ),
```

The Above Code Doesn't Show any output? Why Please Help

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities:

- Check your internet connection permission in main folder/ AndroidManifest.xml.
- Confirm that have you added `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` into
- Check dependency settings which you have used.

If it doesn't work, please post the whole code or logs and screenshot of your app.

Comment: when i give this link https://cdn.syncfusion.com/content/PDFViewer/flutter-succinctly.pdf it show the pdf